# Combinations and Permutations

Tags: permutation, combinations, probability, discrete-mathematics

A certain classroom has two rows of seats. The front row contains 8 seats and the back row contains 10 seats. How many ways are there to seat 15 students if a certain group of 4 of them refuses to sit in the back row and if a certain group of 5 others refuses to sit in the front row?

My approach:
4 has to go front and 5 has to go back.
So I splited them into 4 groups

```
1) 4 front 4 others / 5 back 2 others
2) 4 front 3 others / 5 back 3 others
3) 4 front 2 others / 5 back 4 others
4) 4 front 1 others / 5 back 5 others
```

However, I cannot put them into equations.

Additionally, if anyone knows website that has many combination problems with detailed solutions, please let me know. Websites that I found has only very basic information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider the three groups of students separately.

- For the group that has to sit in the front row, there are `8 Perm 4`
  different possible places for them to sit.
- For the group that has to sit in the back row, there are `10 Perm 5` different 
  possible places for them to sit.
- For the remaining `6` students, there will always be `18 - 4 - 5 = 9` seats left
  for them to choose from, hence a total of `9 Perm 6` choices.

All together this yields `(8!/4!)(10!/5!)(9!/3!) = 3072577536000`.

**Note**: This is eerily similar to Problem 14 from Chapter 3 in R. Brualdi, *Introductory combinatorics*, is this for a homework?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just studying for an exam. The problem is from book, Introduction to Discrete Mathematics, 2nd Ed. by Steven Roman Chapter 4.5 Problem 25.